# Using draggable jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a popup window([here](http://jsfiddle.net/z6qabpLh/)).

HTML:

```
<div id = "window">
    <div id = "title"> "some title"
    </div>  
    <div id = "innerDiv"> 
    </div>     
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#window
{
    height:200px;
    width:150px;
    border: 5px solid red; 
}

#innerDiv
{
    height:90%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #00ff00; 
}

#title
{
    cursor:move;
    height:10%;
    width:100%;
    background-color: yellow; 
}
```

jQUERY:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#title').draggable({appendTo:'div'});
});
```

I want to make this window draggale only when I drag a title line but, now I can dragg only the title line the rest window is staying on his place.

My question is how can I make draggable window not only the title line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#window").draggable({ handle: "#title" });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z6qabpLh/2/

Answer (score 1):

To make the `window` element draggable, simply change:

```
   $('#title').draggable({appendTo:'div'});
```

to:

```
   $('#window').draggable();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z6qabpLh/1/

To have the `title` element as the [handle](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#handle) then you can do:

```
   $('#window').draggable({handle: "#title"});
```